# Самый быстрый способ получить метаданные из файла- картинки

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, каким способом можно быстро считать метаданные у большого числа картинок? Например, ширину и высоту.
Как, я понимаю, стандартная библиотеке .NET грузит картинки целеком в память. А можно ли без этого?

Интересует JPG и PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Для PNG:
Читаем [PNG спецификацию](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html), пишем простенький код:

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    byte[] header = new byte[8];
    fs.Read(header, 0, 8);
    if (!header.SequenceEqual(new byte[] { 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10 }))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("not a png file");

    var br = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII, true);
    while (fs.Position != fs.Length)
    {
        uint chunkLength = br.ReadUInt32BE();
        string chunkType = new string(br.ReadChars(4));
        if (chunkType == "IHDR")
        {
            // читаем чанк
            uint width = br.ReadUInt32BE();
            uint height = br.ReadUInt32BE();
            byte bitDepth = br.ReadByte();
            byte colorType = br.ReadByte();
            byte comprMethod = br.ReadByte();
            byte filterMethod = br.ReadByte();
            byte interlaceMethod = br.ReadByte();
            return;
        }
        else
            // пропускаем чанк
            fs.Position += chunkLength;
        uint crc = br.ReadUInt32BE();
    }
}
```

Для JPEG. Спецификации не нашел, только [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/102521/). Работать будет не для всех файлов, а только для самого распространенного формата. Сложно найти примеры других форматов.

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    var br = new BinaryReader(fs, Encoding.ASCII, true);
    ushort marker = br.ReadUInt16BE();
    if (marker != 0xFFD8)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("not valid jpeg file");

    while (fs.Position != fs.Length)
    {
        marker = br.ReadUInt16BE();
        ushort length = br.ReadUInt16BE();
        if (marker == 0xFFC0)
        {
            byte precision = br.ReadByte();
            ushort height = br.ReadUInt16BE();
            ushort width = br.ReadUInt16BE();
            fs.Position += length - 7;
            return;
        }
        else
            fs.Position += length - 2;
    }
}
```

Для работы понадобятся `extension` методы отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928490/what-are-three-ways-to-get-a-big-endian-binaryreader

```
static class BinaryReaderExtensionMethods
{
    static public UInt16 ReadUInt16BE(this BinaryReader br)
    {
        return (UInt16)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(br.ReadInt16());
    }
    static public UInt32 ReadUInt32BE(this BinaryReader br)
    {
        return (UInt32)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(br.ReadInt32());
    }
}
```

Comment: Спецификации можно найти на https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format, а дополнительно парсить секцию Е0, ее найти проще по сигнатуре (хотя иногда ее может и не быть)

Comment: Искать по сигнатуре плохой подход. Во-первых это противоречит задаче, ведь требуется самый быстрый способ прочитать мета-данные. Для поиска сигнатуры приходится читать все подряд. А во-вторых сигнатура совершенно случайно может оказатся где-нибудь в данных.

Comment: В данном случае сигнатура достаточно большая - 6 байт константны и размер секции предсказуем, что дает достаточную точность. Во-вторых, данная секция в самом начале. В принципе, твой вариант был бы лучше, если ты учитывал секции с фиксированным размером данных, а так, идея с так называемыми стаффинг-байтами, позволяет искать маркеры в потоке просто так

Answer (score 0):

Возможен вариант через System.Drawing.Image с использованием метода  Image.FromStream (stream, false, false). Когда мы передаем во 2-й и 3-й параметры false, то Image не будет использовать информацию о цветах и проводить валидацию данных, за счет чего скорость возрастает примерно в 100 раз. Средняя скорость выполнения кода Image.FromStream (stream) ~ 444 мс, а кода Image.FromStream (stream, false, false) ~ 61500 мс. Время выполнения указано для 512 картинок общим размером 1,11 Гб.
Вот код

```
 public static List<float[]> ReadResolution(string path)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");
        var resolutionList = new List<float[]>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
           var fstream = File.OpenRead(file);
           var img = Image.FromStream(fstream, false, false);
           resolutionList.Add(new  float[]{ img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution });
           fstream.Close();
        }
        return resolutionList;
    }
```

Comment: А ты с покозателями времени не напутал? Ты говоришь, что метод с доп флагами быстрее, но МС что-то большой.

Comment: Я не знаю чем ты руководствуешься, говоря, что МС слишком большой, но нет, не напутал. Проверял на 512 файлах, если что.