# Как получить ширину и высоту картинки не открывая ее? (Или прочитать метаданные)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Необходимо получить ширину и высоту картинки, но не открывать фаил, так как с помощью скрипта буду проходить огромное количество файлов и на их открытие может уйти много времени.

Как можно стандартными средствами Python получить эти размеры? Нужно только под Windows, проводник как-то получает эти размеры, например при наведении на изображение, и врятли проводнику для этого нужно открывать фаил.

Подойдет вариант и с чтением метаданных, есть ли готовая библиотека для этого? и может ли встроенный модуль - `image` загружать только метаданные а не фаил целиком?

Форматы изображений: `png, jpg, tiff`

Comment: Вот пример кода на c# для png и jpg https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707924/9784

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Самый быстрый способ получить метаданные из файла- картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707909/%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев язык же не тот

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Speed

> This needed 3.21 seconds for 30336 images (JPGs from 31x21 to 424x428, training data from National Data Science Bowl on Kaggle)

---

полный ответ находится тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34704661/4794368 (eng)

---

Pillow имеет схожий интерфейс с PIL, но работает в том числе на Python 3.

### установка

> перед установкой удалить PIL

```
pip install Pillow
```

если нет административных прав (sudo) можно воспользоваться флагом `--user`

```
pip install --user Pillow
```

больше информации об установке [тут](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/) в разделе **installation** например:

> Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL.

### узнать размер

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open(filepath) as img:
    width, height = img.size
```

Comment: `Как получить ширину и высоту картинки не открывая ее?` -> `with Image.open(filepath) as img:` -> `не открывая` -> `Image.open` :) Думаю, автор имел ввиду, что нужно не загружая/открывая полностью картинку получить ее размер, потому что есть разница между считыванием всей картинки в мегабайт или ее первые 100 байт чтобы получить тот же результат -- узнать ее размер. А если нужно тысячи картинок проверить?

Comment: Image.open не обязательно означает "открытие" картинки. есть такие штуки как Stream и они тоже "открываются". как бы то ни было ©3.21 seconds for 30336 images

Comment: т.е. `Image.open` ленивый и не считывает всю картинку, пока к ней не обратиться, но к моменту открытия знает ее размер по метаданным?

Comment: 1) я не знаю как работает данная библиотека 2) возможно информация о ширине хранится в начале файла (что логично предположить). например для JPEG https://stackoverflow.com/a/24285517/4794368 ©ffc0 in binary formate, the the four,five bytes are hight and six and seven bytes are width (eg: [ff c0] d8 c3 c2 [ff da] [00 ff])

Comment: Похоже, все-таки ленивый: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open